# d3.js graph not displaying on asp.net page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, svg, d3.js

As the title says, i cant get the graph to display within the "MainContent" placeholder on my asp.NET page. If  i change the select from "MainContent" to "body" then the graph does display at the bottom of the page.

Code snippet:

> var w = 960,
>               h = 500,
>               r = 30,
>               fill = d3.scale.category20();
>
> ```
>     var force = d3.layout.force()
>         .charge(-120)
>         .linkDistance(60)
>         .size([w, h]);
>
>     var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
>         .attr("width", w)
>         .attr("height", h);
>
>     d3.json("graph.json", function (json) {
>         var link = svg.selectAll("line")
>             .data(json.links)
>           .enter().append("svg:line");
>
>         var node = svg.selectAll("g myCircleText")
>           .data(json.nodes)
>
>         var elemEnter = node.enter()
>           .append("g")
>
>         elemEnter.append("text")
>           //.attr("dx", function (d) { return -20 })
>           .text(function (d) { return d.name })
>
>         var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
>           .attr("r", r)
>           .style("fill", function (d) { return fill(d.group); })
>             .style("stroke", function (d) { return d3.rgb(fill(d.group)).darker(); })
>             .call(force.drag);
>
>         force
>             .nodes(json.nodes)
>             .links(json.links)
>             .on("tick", tick)
>             .start();
>
>         function tick(e) {
>
>             // Push sources up and targets down to form a weak tree.
>             var k = 6 * e.alpha;
>             json.links.forEach(function (d, i) {
>                 d.source.y -= k;
>                 d.target.y += k;
>             });
>
>             circle.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
>                 .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; });
>
>             link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
>                 .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
>                 .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
>                 .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
>         }
>     });`
> ```

I can't get text to display on each node either, i have done quite a bit of searching but have yet to solve either issue.

**UPDATE:**
I have managed to get text to display within my graph. However the text does not display within the circle, rather it displays in the top left corner of the svg container. I have updated the code snippet to reflect this.

**UPDATE 2:**
I now have the graph displaying in its correct position. The solution was as simple as placing the script within a div, and then selecting said div within the script. I still have not figured out how to display the text within a circle.

Comment: Try to provide a minimal node working code for what you're doing. Please also tell us why you think this is link with ASP (it shouldn't, D3.js is purely front-end)

Comment: The code above is working, but not displaying the graph unless i change the selected d3 area to "body". Im not sure that the problem is asp related, but i dont see any reason why it wouldn't display within a content placeholder.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML generated by ASP?

Comment: Its an empty page, other then the 3 place holders inherited from the site.master(which i havent added to yet). Would you still like me to copy the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, hope this helps somebody out who is in a similar spot. Heres my solution. Im open to correction on whether or not this is a well constructed solution, however it works for me.

**EDIT**
If anybody knows how to add a marker to the end of each line, i would appreciate your input!

Code snippet:

> ```
>             var w = 960,
>             h = 500,
>             r = 35,
>             fill = d3.scale.category20();
>
>         var force = d3.layout.force()
>             .charge(-500)
>             .linkDistance(180)
>             .size([w, h]);
>
>         var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
>             .attr("width", w)
>             .attr("height", h);
>
>         d3.json("graph.json", function (json) {
>             var link = svg.selectAll("line")
>                 .data(json.links)
>               .enter().append("svg:line");
>
>             var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
>                 .data(json.nodes)
>                 .enter().append("circle")
>                 .attr("r", r)
>             circle.style("fill", "#2185c5")
>                 .call(force.drag);
>
>             var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
>                 .data(json.nodes)
>                 .enter().append("text")
>                 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
>             text.style("fill", "black")
>             text.style("font-weight", "900")
>                 //.call(force.drag)
>                 .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
>
>             force
>                 .nodes(json.nodes)
>                 .links(json.links)
>                 .on("tick", tick)
>                 .start();
>
>             function tick(e) {
>
>                 // Push sources up and targets down to form a weak tree.
>                 var k = 6 * e.alpha;
>                 json.links.forEach(function (d, i) {
>                     d.source.y -= k;
>                     d.target.y += k;
>                 });
>
>                 circle.attr("transform", transform);
>                 text.attr("transform", transform);
>
>
>
>                 link.attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
>                     .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
>                     .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
>                     .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
>             }
>
>             function transform(d) {
>                 return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
>             }
>         });
> ```